# Restore existing conversation of custom userId in Botpress

Tags: javascript, node.js, botpress

On our website, we use Botpress' [website embedding](https://botpress.com/docs/messaging-channels/botpress-webchat/website-embedding) function

```
<script>
  window.botpressWebChat.init({
    host: OWN_URL:BOTPRESS_PORT,
    botId: "test12345"
  })
</script>
```

which displays the bot and allows interacting with it. Up to this point, everything works as expected.

However, in the next step, we intend to define a custom `userId` to store existing conversations and restore them, when logging back into the system. While [Botpress allows defining a custom userId](https://botpress.com/docs/messaging-channels/botpress-webchat/website-embedding#configuring-a-custom-user-id), it seems not to be used for storing and reloading the current conversation at a later point. Instead, even when initializing the chat/conversation with this `userId`:

```
<script>
  window.botpressWebChat.init({
    host: OWN_URL:BOTPRESS_PORT,
    botId: "test12345",
    userId: "example12345"
  })
</script>
```

then retrieving the `conversationId` from the Networks-Tab and trying to reload the conversation in another window using:

```
<script>
  window.botpressWebChat.init({
    host: OWN_URL:BOTPRESS_PORT,
    botId: "test12345",
    userId: "example12345",
    conversationId: ID_RETRIEVED_FROM_NETWORKS_TAB
  })
</script>
```

Botpress sends a `"The conversation ID doesn't belong to that user"` error message, which can be found within [this file](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/blob/master/modules/channel-web/src/backend/api.ts).

Debugging the point of error tells us that even though the conversation is found:

```
{
  id: 'd3178f66-3b4f-493e-aa39-ce8fcc2195a3',
  clientId: '076ea353-fcd7-4984-869e-713e12b0176f',
  userId: 'a317d806-a6ad-493f-b3b3-70c792f29445',
  createdOn: 2022-07-15T16:39:56.523Z
}
```

the `userId` differs (e.g., `705d31e8-c6e0-4e7b-a28f-f0da46390653`) -> `conversation.userId !== userId`.

It seems like setting a `userId` when initializing the bot (or at a later point – we tried this as well) does not have an influence on the `userId` set in the conversation.

Now the question is as follows: How can you restore existing conversations of a custom `userId` in Botpress? Or is this a Pro-feature when referring to [user authentication](https://botpress.com/docs/enterprise/user-management-and-security/authentication-methods#user-authentication)?

Our main idea is just about using an existing user (of our system), e.g., `example12345` to have a conversation and when logging back into the system (from another computer, for instance) to restore this conversation.

Thanks for any hint!

Additional links:

- Botpress inject-Script which is used for website embedding can be found [here](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/blob/master/modules/channel-web/assets/inject.js)
- Issue showing how to "test" with Botpress can be found [here](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/issues/3749)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### TL;DR

Any alphanumeric string from 24 to 40 characters long will work for `userId`.

#### Research

According to the source code, a valid `userId` must be [less than `USER_ID_MAX_LENGTH` caracters long](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/blob/master/modules/channel-web/src/backend/api.ts#L50) which [is `40`](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/blob/master/modules/channel-web/src/backend/api.ts#L26) and [match the `/[a-z0-9-_]+/i` pattern](https://github.com/botpress/botpress/blob/master/modules/channel-web/src/backend/api.ts#L52).

Although your example value (`example12345`) meets the criteria, it indeed doesn't work.

You seem to indicate that the framework generates [UUIDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/UUID), so, after testing some, turns out **UUIDs work**.

[`nanoid`](https://github.com/ai/nanoid) [uses the same pattern by default](https://github.com/ai/nanoid/blame/main/README.md#L17), so, after testing some, turns out **any string works starting from 24 characters long**.

#### Reproduction

The following code exposes `nanoId` and initializes the framework with a `userId` coming from [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) :

```html
<script src="http://localhost:3000/assets/modules/channel-web/inject.js"></script>
<script type="module">
    import { nanoid } from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/nanoid/nanoid.js';
    window.nanoid = nanoid;

    window.botpressWebChat.init({
        host: "http://localhost:3000",
        botId: "test",
        userId: window.localStorage.getItem('userId')
    });
    setTimeout(() => window.botpressWebChat.sendEvent({ type: 'show' }), 1000);
</script>
```

Step 1 : generate a first ID and say *Hi*
[image: Step 1]
Step 2 : generate a second ID and say *Hi*
[image: Step 2]
Step 3 : reload the first ID and retrieve my previous *Hi* (notice the timestamp checks out)
[image: Step 3]

#### Additional info

When testing for the first time, I noticed I didn't need to specify `userId` to retrieve my conversation after reloading.

Comment: It seems like that you saved our day or maybe the entire week. Please let me verify that your solution works in our production environment and I will accept it and award the bounty afterwards. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome ! If my research turns out to be conclusive, you may report the min length bug on the repo *(or I could, but it would be less appropriate as I'm not an actual user of the framework)*. Perhaps they should also know that their RegExp doesn't validate the string from start to end (`userId` = `###` is invalid, but `a##`, `#a#` and `##a` are). Surrounding the expression with `^` and `$` would solve this.

Comment: As far as we could test in our production environment, everything works as expected, despite some console errors due to an undefined `currentConversation` within the `lite.bundle.js`. However, we guess that initializing the chat with the previous `conversationId` or updating the version of Botpress used helps at solving this issue, as well. Thanks again for helping us!

And please feel free to report the bug you described above. I am pretty sure that the developers would be interested in it as well.